# Margins different between printers, one has larger margins

Tags: printer

at work I have two printers at work and I need to use them to print checks - which are super specific with what the bottom margin needs to be - because the MICR line needs to be like 3/16ths from the bottom of the page.

On printer one, the bottom margin is rather small, consistently - close to 3/16ths - as it needs to be.

On printer two, the bottom margin is larger, closer to 5/16ths. Its like everything has been moved up or shifted, or maybe scaled imperceptibly. How can I get this printer to have the same small margin?

Printer one is a HP LaserJet P3015 printer and printer two - the large margin printer is a HP LaserJet P4015 printer.

Comment: Are you using the same paper size in both?

Comment: yep! I am using A4 size special paper

Comment: Printer drivers interpret print jobs differently.

Comment: Exactly. You couldn't any works. It depends to printer driver. Dirty Solution: create two pages with different format.